# How to check what props changed in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to check what props changed (without storing old props elsewhere) inside `componentWillReceiveProps` ?

i.e.

```
componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
  if( /* newProps.profileImage is different to previous props */ ) /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Note that the function `componentWillReceiveProps` is now **deprecated**. Quoting [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops):

> If you used `componentWillReceiveProps` for re-computing some data only
>   when a prop changes, use a memoization helper instead.

This refers to the case where the your check inside `componentWillReceiveProps` was to avoid unnecessarily recomputing the same thing many times. In the [linked blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization), it suggests caching the result of the expensive function so that it can be looked up, rather than recomputed. This can be done using a helper such as [memoize-one](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one).

> If you used `componentWillReceiveProps` to “reset” some state when a
>   prop changes, consider either making a component fully controlled or
>   fully uncontrolled with a key instead.

Again, the [linked blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization) describes this in more detail, but in a nutshell:

- The "fully controlled" component refers to a functional component with no state (the parent component is responsible for handling the state).
- The "fully uncontrolled" alternative is one that *only* uses the `props` to set the *initial state*, and then ignores all further changes to the props.

> In very rare cases, you might want to use the `getDerivedStateFromProps`
>   lifecycle as a last resort.

This function receives `(props, state)` and returns any changes to the state before `render` is called, giving you the control to do whatever you want.

---

#### Original answer, for older versions of React

At the point in time that this [lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) is called, `this.props` refers to the previous set of props.

To compare a single property `foo` on the the new props with the same property on the old ones, you can just compare `newProps.foo` with `this.props.foo`. So in your example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
  if( newProps.profileImage !== this.props.profileImage ) /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 32):

You can also loop through all the props to see what changed.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  for (const index in nextProps) {
    if (nextProps[index] !== this.props[index]) {
      console.log(index, this.props[index], '-->', nextProps[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Since React 16.3, componentWillReceiveProps is not recommended to use, please refer [unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) documentation on react website.

Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(nextProps.profileImage !== prevState.profileImage ) {
    return {stateFoo: 'valueBar'};
  }
}
```

The returned value behaves similarly as `setState`.

Comment: The second parameter to `getDerivedStateFromProps` is the previous *state* and not the previous state of `props`. This will only work if you copy the props you want to check to the state.

Comment: The correct contract of method is `getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` there is no access to previous prop or state

Answer (score 3):

You can still compare to `this.props.profileImage`, because it does not get updated until after `componentWilReceiveProps` is called. For example, in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops), this example is used:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    likesIncreasing: nextProps.likeCount > this.props.likeCount
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note to anyone who finds this in the future. It appears that componentWillReceiveProps() is going to be deprecated. Docs now suggest you use getDerivedStateFromProps(). Explainations as to why can be found here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check if a specific prop changed. `this.props` refers to the props *before* they have changed. So for example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if( newProps.profileImage != this.props.profileImage ) {
    /* do stuff */
  }
}
```

*Note:* The props don't necessarily change every time the method is called, so it is worth testing to see which prop changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement logic like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
class DataTable extends React.Component {
  state = {
      previousProps: null // Keep snapshot of current props in State & never change this through setState()
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, currentState) {
      if (JSON.stringify(props) === JSON.stringify(currentState.previousProps)){
          //Here it's mean that props are not changed!!!
          return null;
      }

      //Here it's mean props are changed!
      //Here You find out what are changed through looping
      //Don't forget to return new props as a state here!
      return {
          previousProps: props,
          //...Pass your new state depending on new props here!
      }

  }


  render() {
      return(
          <View>
               {...}
          </View>
      )
  }
}
```