# cloning the (newarray) from my propsArray in defaultState and keeping the data of the cloned not changing when the data of propsArray changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

i want to clone an array from props in my default state, and also when the original propsArray changes i want to keep the (cloned array as propsArray by default) and (not the updated propsArray)

Answer (score 0):

You can clone an array like this:

```
const nums = ['1', '2', '3"];

const nums2 = [...nums];
```

That way this new array does not reference to the old array address in memory.

```
console.log(nums === nums2);
// false --> it's pointing to a new memory space
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer from this [How to check what props changed in componentWillReceiveProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654750/how-to-check-what-props-changed-in-componentwillreceiveprops)

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
      if(nextProps.profileImage !== prevState.profileImage ) {
        return {stateFoo: 'valueBar'};
      }
    }
```

You could check whether you have props or not, and if it passes the condition, set the state and save your propsArray. If it doesn't just discard your new array and keep the original one in the state.